# subprocess python filenotfounderror: [winerror 2]

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I've been using Jupyter Notebook to learn [Principal Component Analysis from kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/ntx32505/d/ludobenistant/hr-analytics/principal-component-analysis-explained/notebook)), but when I run this code

```
     from subprocess import check_output
     print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))
```

I got an error below

```
FileNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-de0e39ca3ab8> in <module>()
      1 from subprocess import check_output
----> 2 print(check_output(["ls", "C:/Users/wanglei/Documents/input"]).decode("utf8"))

D:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    624 
    625     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
--> 626                **kwargs).stdout
    627 
    628 

D:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in run(input, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    691         kwargs['stdin'] = PIPE
    692 
--> 693     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    694         try:
    695             stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)

D:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds)
    945                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    946                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 947                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    948         except:
    949             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

D:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1222                                          env,
   1223                                          cwd,
-> 1224                                          startupinfo)
   1225             finally:
   1226                 # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe
```

The path is correct, and it seems that all the call from subprocess  will fail similarly.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code runs the [`ls` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls), which [is available on all POSIX-conforming systems](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/ls.html).

You are using Microsoft Windows. Microsoft Windows does not conform to POSIX by default. For instance, there is no `ls` binary. Therefore, subprocess cannot find the file `ls`, and thus emits a `FileNotFoundError`.

You can install [Microsoft's Bash on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which will give you ls.

However, the pythonic and more portable way to list a directory is not to use subprocess in the first place, but the built-in [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.listdir):

```
import os
print(os.listdir('../input'))
```

Comment: Yes, you make a good point,and this works,but could you analyze why the subprocess module didn't work?Thx

Comment: The subprocess module works fine. There is just no `ls` binary on your filesystem. Therefore, subprocess cannot find the `ls` file, and thus emits an `FileNotFoundError`.

Comment: Yes,I think you are right,all the example I run came from official website was   baesd on  POSIX,that's why the call all failed,bacause the Windows just do not follow the  POSIX. LOL

Comment: We can just use, print(os.listdir('input')) , if you are using os package.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have the same question. Using the below codes provided by Phihag works good for me on Jupiter Notebook on Windows. Thank you.

```
    import os
    print(os.listdir('../input'))
```

Answer (score -1):

try specifying the working directory by adding a cwd arguement, this should work

```
import os, subprocess
cwd = os.getcwd()
proc = subprocess.Popen(["ls" ,"../input"], cwd=cwd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.stdout.read().decode("utf8")
```

Comment: That is already the default for `cwd`. The problem here is also not related to the argument of `ls` (if it were, there would not be a `FileNotFound` error, but an error message from ls), but the binary itself.

Comment: unfortunately,it throws the same error.could this be the problem of subprocess module?